# Android Get spinner text from tablerow

Tags: android, spinner, tablerow

I have a tablelayout with 3 fields each row.

First and second are text and they work fine but third, is a spinner and it works fine until I try to recover the value kept.

I have this code for reading info from table:

```
 TableRow row = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
 TextView a= (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
 TextView b= (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
 Log.d(LOGTAG, (String) a.getText());
 Spinner c= (Spinner) row.getChildAt(2);
```

If I try to use Spinner line, it fails. I tried, many diferents pieces of code, sure actual doesn't work because last line fails always...

I create the spinner this way:

```
                    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    spinnerArray.add("0%");
                    spinnerArray.add("25%");
                    spinnerArray.add("50%");
                    spinnerArray.add("75%");
                    spinnerArray.add("100%");

                    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(home_screen.this);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(home_screen.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);


            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

            row.addView(spinner);
```

Answering to first answer, this is the output:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
    at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
    at com.gps.distance.home_screen.guardar(home_screen.java:217)
    at com.gps.distance.home_screen.access$1000(home_screen.java:22)
    at com.gps.distance.home_screen$3.onClick(home_screen.java:188)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure it has value? If it doesn't, you'll get a NullPointerException. Generally, if you want to do something with the value, you should use the OnItemSelectedListener: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)

Comment: Yes, I think so. I can choose a value between 5 shown when I create a row in table

Comment: you said the last line always fails. how? does it throw an exception what does it say?

Comment: Yes, If I write try and catch, it does anything but if I don't, program closes.

Comment: what does logcat say?

Comment: android.widget.RadioGroup cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner

Comment: then that's your problem in position 2 on that row you have a RadioGroup not a spinner. I'd recommend you set an id on your spinner to find it later, I'll post an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to make sure you have a unique ID for your spinner so that you can get it later (normally I'd recommend defining more of this in xml but I'm not sure what you're doing so this is not best practice)

```
//add spinner
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(home_screen.this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(home_screen.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
spinner.setId(android.R.id.list);
row.addView(spinner);
```

now to get that spinner later from the row we just added it to we use the following.

```
//to get spinner from table
TableRow row;
Spinner c = (Spinner) row.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
String percentage = (String) c.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because I have one spinner for each row in table. So I think if I set the same id in all of them, it crash??. It fails at spin.getSelectedItem()

Comment: when you say it fails you need to say how, does it fail at casting the value of selected item? or does it fail because spin is null? also because you're searching a distinct row for an id (where there's only 1 view with a matching id) there's no issue with setting all the spinners with the same Id.

Comment: I added output in my question, is a big output

Comment: if I put this: if(c==null) Log.d(LOGTAG, "NULL"); it prints that, so c is null after getting it

Comment: I'd say do some debugging make sure your view is in the row as you expect, check to see if the spinner Id is getting set. Really I'd recommend implementing a template view like you would do with a Listview or just pick one of the many examples online (look up android data table view)